# Testing mixed objc/swift code

Tags: objective-c, swift, testing

I have class A in objc which internally uses class B made in swift. Each of them has a test made in the same language. The problem with swift is that the class shouldn't be included in the tests target, but objc does and you get a compilation error. One solution would be to disable testability but i ran into another problem, If a class happens to be a VC when you get it from storyboard it has a different module name, so i have again problems with my specific VC tests. Another solution would be to write only objc tests. Did you run into this problem? Is there any other escape? Thanks.

Comment: While i was trying to pursue my idea i found that the situation is even worse. My tests involving NSManagedObjects is failing, i assume also because of the module name. I'm stuck :(